# Shorthand for foo={foo} bar={bar}

Tags: jsx

I'm new to JSX and I have found myself doing a TON of `<Component foo={foo} bar={bar}>`

To not end up double typing `foo` and `bar` I was using object spread `<Component {...{foo, bar}}>`

However I think this is not transpiled by JSX, instead it is an expression executed at runtime, which is wasteful overhead. Is there anyway to tell shorten `foo={foo} bar={bar}` to something like just `<Component foo bar>`? Right now if I do this it sets `foo` and `bar` to `true`.

Comment: I do think that any other solution would also be a **wasteful runtime overhead** as you mentioned.. i'm afraid the good old code labor is still prefared

Comment: Aw drats, thanks @ymz for your reply! :)